# Timer 300-W Smart Dimmer Outlet

Tags: smart-home, smart-plugs

I have a 300-watt floor lamp in my bedroom with a built-in dimmer. Living in the northern hemisphere, mornings are darker now, and I'm having a harder time waking up in the morning. I'd like to have a system where my floor lamp will turn on automatically in the morning, but gradually so I don't blind myself every time.

I assume there are smart home devices that meet my requirements but searching the web hasn't been very productive. What products would you recommend for this? Thanks in advance.

- Turn on gradually
- At a pre-programmed time
- capable of 300 watts or more
- Smart outlet (not a wall switch, bulb, etc)
- Control via Android phone
- Prefer no additional base stations or other unneeded products.

Comment: What is your budget? Maybe I can help.

Comment: Price isn't an issue, within reason. I don't own the property, so modifications to my home are out of the question. Otherwise, please, shoot.

Answer (score 6):

Update: This device did not meet the requirement of scheduling a gradual dimming. It only turns on or off fully.

I bought the Leviton DW3HL-1BW.

Answer (score 1):

I found this on Amazon and it isn't too expensive (around $50). Here is the link for the [WiFi Dimmer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003IHTZDU). This is capable of handling 300W (120v 2.5amps) and can be controlled via a phone, google home, or Alexa. It can work with a timer, and there are no other accessories, like a central hub, required.

Hope this works for you!

Comment: I also believe that you can program it to slowly turn on the lamps with your alarm... if that helps.

Comment: This is the exact Leviton device that I already mentioned in my above answer, which does NOT support dimming on a timer.

Comment: Hey, sorry about that... I just edited it. This one also says it can dim the lights gradually. I think Amazon has a better return policy too if it doesn't work for you.

Comment: I received the Insteon LampLinc Smart Plug from Amazon. Though the product page states that it can be used without a base station, that apparently only means that you can press the buttons on the side of it directly. I've ordered the Insteon Central Controller Hub.